Remove SwiftData auto-update
How can I remove auto-updating of my list when @Model is changed in sheet? I want to save the updates only when Update button is pressed, and cancel updates on sheet swipe-down.
I have passed a tapped item as @Bindable to sheet by:
.sheet(item: $itemToUpdate) { item in
    UpdateItemView(item: item)
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
 }

In my UpdateItemView, I have an item declared as:
@Bindable var item: MyItem

As I see everyone suggests using Bindable, is there any other way?
I have tried with setting isAutosaveEnabled for modelContainerbut no luck.


EDIT:
I have also tried to remove @Bindable in my UpdateItemView and declared item as:
var item: MyItem

and declared all item's properties as @State variables so I can save them when Update button is tapped.
But for some reason, my item appears to be nil and .sheet opens white screen.
I present sheet like this:
.sheet(isPresented: $showingUpdateSheet) {
    if let itemToUpdate {
        UpdateItemView(item: itemToUpdate)
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
    }
}

where itemToUpdate is declared as:
@State private var itemToUpdate: MyItem?

and assigned a value in List's swipe action as:
.swipeActions {
    Button {
        itemToUpdate = item
        showingUpdateSheet = true
    } label: {
        Label("update", systemImage: "pencil")
    }
    .tint(.blue)
}

How my UpdateItemView looks like after separating all item's properties as @States:
struct UpdateItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var item: MyItem
    
    @State private var title: String = ""
    @State private var description: String = ""
    ...
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
    ...
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
        title = item.title
        description = item.desc
        ...
    })
}

I am saving my item on Update button tap:
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
        Button("Update") {
            item.title = title
            item.desc = description
            context.insert(item)
            dismiss()
        }
    }
 }


Show the source for UpdateView; presumably you are binding your controls in that view directly to the properties of item; you need to use local @State properties that you set to the equivalent item properties in onAppear and then only update the properties of item in your update action handler

Or create and use a local ModelContext that you use to load and save your MyItem object.

@Paulw11 I have tried that way with @States too, but the item appears to be nil. Can you please check the EDIT part at the bottom of my question.

You still want your item to be a binding. You need to extract the properties of your item into simple state properties. Declare @State var name ="" and then in .onAppear set self.name=itemToUpdate.name and so on. You need to put the state values back into itemToUpdate when you want to persist the changes.  Please show the source for updateItemView

@Paulw11 I have already tried exactly the same with @States and .onAppear, but as I said, item is nil and screen is blank. Maybe up to Binding as you said now. I have updated a question.

item should be a binding and you don't insert a new item when you save.

yes @Binding solves my initial issue with @Bindable, thank you. What also caused a blank screen was if let itemToUpdate in .sheet, it needs to be removed. Would you like to post an answer for @Binding so I can accept it?

You should be using sheet(item:) instead of sheet(isPresented:) and @Bindable is what you are supposed to use with model (Observable) classes.

@JoakimDanielson yeah it worked perfectly but as I did not like the part I showed on the gif above.

The below sheet gives the expected behaviour although it is different in some aspects like that I use a Form but that should not be relevant to the solving the issue.
struct UpdateItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    let item: MyItem

    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var description = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $title)
            TextField("Description", text: $description)

            Spacer()

            Button("Update") {
                updateItem()
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            title = item.title
            description = item.itemDescription
        })
    }

    private func updateItem() {
        item.title = title
        item.itemDescription = description
    }
}

The main changes from the original view here is that item is let declared and that I do not do insert the item property (again) after updating it in the updateItem function.
And the view is opened using
.sheet(item: $itemToUpdate) { item in
     UpdateItemView(item: item)
        .presentationDetents([.large, .medium])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
}

This gives me no update of the background list until I press Update and the sheet is dismissed.

@stackish any feedback on this?
